# Registering a class' function in LuaBridge, then calling it via a lua script?

Tags: c++, class, lua, luabridge

Whenever I run the program, it prints nothing to the console.
This works fine if I don't use a class and just do it all in main().

The moment I put it in a class, I start having problems.
What am I doing wrong?

```
using namespace luabridge;

myClass::myClass()
{
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    getGlobalNamespace(L).beginClass<myClass>("myClass").addFunction("printMessage", &myClass::printMessage).endClass();
    luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
}

void myClass::printMessage(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

My lua script "test.lua"

I've tried

```
c = myClass()
c:printMessage("You can call C++ functions from Lua!")
```

and

```
myClass:printMessage("You can call C++ functions from Lua!")
```

and

```
printMessage("You can call C++ functions from Lua!")
```

Comment: 5 hours and 30 minutes later after trying this out I gave up, posted this, and am now hoping for an answer soon. Otherwise, I can't continue. I can't believe I tried to get this working for over 5 hours, only to have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options to do what you want:

1. If you want to construct a `myClass` instance in lua, and use it like your first example, you need to also export a constructor after the `beginClass`:

   `.addConstructor <void (*) (void)> ()`
2. Construct a `myClass` instance in C++, and then pass it to lua using some other function.  Then lua may access it like:

   `myClassInstance:printMessage("Hello")`
3. Make `printMessage` static, and export it with the following:

   `.addStaticFunction("printMessage", &myClass::printMessage)`

   Then you can call it in lua using:

   `myClass.printMessage("Hello")`

Notice the difference between `.` and `:` in the calls. `.` accesses like a static and `:` accesses like an instance.

Comment: Is it at all possible, for future reference, to also include how to do #1 with certain parameters?
I had problems with #1, because my class actually has two parameters (an SFML window and a "Player" object from Player.cpp) and I couldn't find the documentation to pass parameters like that. I understand how to pass strings or integers, but I had errors when trying to pass objects.

Comment: Thank you. #3 worked flawlessly, and I assume #2 would work too (I didn't try it, but I know it would work because now I understand why it wasn't working for me originally).

Comment: To use other classes as parameters to constructors or functions, you will need to also register those classes with LuaBridge. So you would need to register the `sf::Window` and `Player` classes and then export any functions you want to call on them from lua.  Now the question is if you are in lua and want to call the `myClass` constructor where do the instances of `Window` and `Player` come from?  You would need to export two more functions to lua to get pointers to those from C++.

Comment: Yea, after thinking about what you said, that wouldn't work very well to register everything. I would rather stick with #2 or #3. Thank you.